# Stolz Cesaro Application

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $b_n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then show that 
$\frac{b_n-1}{\ln b_n} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I was told to prove this using Stolz-Cesaro's Lemma.

Edit: $b_n = \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$. Sorry for the confusion.

Thank you!

The hard part is, even if I apply Stolz Cesaro's Lemma, the function we have

$\frac{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}{\ln {\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}}}$

Which is even more complex to compute. I tried repeating Stolz Cesaro again, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you really use that? In the assumption some sequence has to be monotone.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the differentiable version of Stolz Cesaro's Lemma: The L'Hospital rule. Let $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{\ln x}$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_n - 1}{\ln b_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(b_n) = \lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$$
if the limit exist. Since

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(x-1)'}{(\ln x)'} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{1/x} =1,$$

By L' Hospital Rule, we have 
$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 1\Rightarrow  \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_n  -1}{\ln b_n} = 1.$$